# Find multiple words using df['var'].str.extract() (Python)?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, extract

I am trying to extract any words in a row of my dataframe using str.extract(), but I end up only getting one word. For example in one of the columns of my dataframe:

```
var1
THIS IS A STRING
```

When I use:

```
df['words'] = df['var1'].str.extract('([A-Z]\w{0,})')
```

The output is

```
var1                words
THIS IS A STRING    THIS
```

How can I extract the whole phrase 'THIS IS A STRING'?

Thank you!

Comment: Your dataframe refers to `var1`, but your extract from `df['test']`. Typo?

Comment: Yes, it was typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by arbitrary whitespace `\s+`  and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `Series`:

```
print df
               var1
0  THIS IS A STRING

print df.var1.str.split('\s+').apply(pd.Series)
      0   1  2       3
0  THIS  IS  A  STRING
```